Quarkus - Custom HttpSecurityPolicy
For the authorization I would like to access the body of a request and compare it with values within the SecurityIdentity.
I have written the following class for this
@ApplicationScoped
public class AuthorizationHandler implements HttpSecurityPolicy {

    @Inject
    SecurityIdentity securityIdentity;

    @Override
    public Uni<CheckResult> checkPermission(RoutingContext routingContext, Uni<SecurityIdentity> identity, AuthorizationRequestContext requestContext) {
        return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(routingContext.request().body().toCompletionStage())
            .onItem()
            .transformToUni(buffer -> {
                if (buffer == null || buffer.length() == 0) {
                    return Uni.createFrom().item(CheckResult.DENY);
                }

                // do some tests
                return Uni.createFrom().item(CheckResult.PERMIT);
            });
    }
}

But here I notice the following:

when I try to access the body, I get a Read timed out
when I try to access the SecurityIdentity, I get a Method threw 'jakarta.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException' exception.

Do you have any inputs for my attempt?
Many thanks in advance

You don’t need to inject the Identity. It’s already available via the method. And can you try to read the buffer without reactive code and add a breakpoint there ?
